# Using Multibranch Pipeline Jenkins job, is it possible to run branch indexing without re-running existing branch builds

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm setting up a new Jenkins job using multibranch pipeline and I have noticed that when a branch is deleted, it only has a strikethrough and isn't actually removed on Jenkins. This is solved by re-running branch indexing. However, I cannot really use this as it will also cause every other branch to rebuild (a consequence of how the repository is updated). Is there some custom code or pipeline/script I can run to re-index without building?

I've already looked at various UI methods such as suppressing SCM triggers, but this also negates push events from Github which is something we want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deleted/merged branch build will disappear after a period of time (<24 hours). It is not removed immediately to show the recently deleted/merged branches and give a chance to review the prior build statuses. It is relatively harmless since the jobs for these branches are deactivated (read-only).

Note that the removal is based on the branch indexing job running at regular interval, so if you have this disabled, it probably won't do it (not sure the SCM webhook calls are enough).